# Stuck on an Implementation for string class

Tags: c++

My goal is to create a method that returns the i-th element (zero-based, just like arrays) of the String it is called on. This method should print out an error message and return the null character (\0) if the location asked for is out-of-range for the string.

```
char String::element(int i) const
{
    if (i < m_str1) 
    {
        cout << s[i]; // also the s here is undefined
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

So I just want to know if this is alright, or do I need to add more, and how can i fix the undefined variable?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Traditionally, that parameter's type should be `std::size_t`.

Comment: what is `s` here anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work correctly you need to change `s` to the member variable pointing to the array of characters. You didn't provide the class definition of `String` so it's hard to say what the name of that member variable is.

You should also change

```
char String::element(int i) const
```

to either

```
char String::element(size_t i) const
```

or

```
char String::element(unsigned int i) const
```

This is because your array of characters should never be accessed with a negative index value. If you don't change `i` to an unsigned value you need to make sure it's equal to or greater than zero, which should never be allowed anyway. Toy should also change `m_str1` to `size_t` or `unsigned int` if it already isn't since the string should never have a negative length.

Applying these suggestions would make `String` and `element()` look something like the following...

```
class String
{
    unsigned int m_str1; // length of character string
    char* m_str; // pointer to the character string
public:
    char String::element(unsigned int i) const;
};

char String::element(unsigned int i) const
{
    if (i < m_str1) 
    {
        return m_str[i]; // Changed s to m_str
    }

    cout << "Error" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even with changing

    char String::element(int i) const to char String::element(unsigned int i) const

still marks i as an error

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? In your question `s` is undefined but `i` doesn't produce an error so how can `i` _still_ be giving you an error?

Comment: well s at first had an undefined error (the variable was not defined), but after I change 's' to return m_str1[i];  then i has an error which is expression must have pointer to object type

Comment: Sorry about that `m_str1` should have been `m_str` and I edited my answer to reflect that. I edited my answer again to make it a little more clear.